# How to reset Network Manager to default?

Tags: networking, 14.10, internet, network-manager

This is what I have in my network menu.

[image]

I've tried many workarounds from deleting entries to all that. Can you suggest any solutions?

Comment: The screenshot has gone, could you add a new one? Better if you transcribe the text shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Purge and Re-Install Network Manager

Do this from the machine locally, and not via SSH or other remote means.

1. Download the necessary package archives:

   ```sh
   dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' network-manager network-manager-* | awk '$1=="i" { print($2) }' | xargs apt-get download
   ```

   If you want to be extra thorough, save their Apt marks:

   ```sh
   apt-mark showauto network-manager network-manager-* | tee apt-mark-auto.txt
   ```
2. Purge the packages:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get purge network-manager network-manager-*
   ```
3. Reinstall the from the previously downloaded package files:

   ```sh
   sudo dpkg -i network-manager*.deb
   ```

   If you saved the Apt marks earlier restore them with:

   ```sh
   xargs -a apt-mark-auto.txt -- sudo apt-mark auto
   ```

Comment: Have fun reinstalling it without a network. Even if its in memory if something goes wrong you are screwed.

Comment: @kagronick, this answer could be enhanced to minimize the risk by downloading the target packages before purging: `apt download $(apt-get remove -s --purge network-manager network-manager-* | awk '/Purg / { printf $2 " " }')`  , purge , then install them back using `sudo dpkg -i network-manager*`

Comment: @user.dz: This downloads the package files *after* they were purged. Try `dpkg-query -l network-manager network-manager-* | awk '/^ii/{print($2)}' | xargs apt download`, the the commands shown in the answer.

Comment: @DavidFoerster , My command was for download only no effective purge. I used `-s` option for simulation or dry run.

Answer (score 10):

In a terminal, run

```
nmcli con
```

This will output something like this:

```
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Wired connection 1        67d66f2c-9a03-4298-8136-35933de5febe   802-3-ethernet    Wed 17 Jun 2015 17:00:08 BST
```

this will list all your connections defined in NetworkManager

So now, pick the one you want to delete either by name or by uuid and run

```
nmcli con delete uuid 67d66f2c-9a03-4298-8136-35933de5febe
```

All the settings associated with that connection will be lost. But it will **not** clean your *nm-applet* menu.

You will need to logout/relogin or reboot for this to be visible in nm-applet menu

Comment: Terminal Says Command not found.

Comment: what did you type ? don't type the $

Comment: $ nmcli con
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Wired connection 1        67d66f2c-9a03-4298-8136-35933de5febe   802-3-ethernet    Wed 17 Jun 2015 17:00:08 BST

Comment: just type `nmcli con`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

A safer option is the following, because the package is not uninstalled

Remove all configuration files of network-manager as superuser (*put sudo before following command*)

```
rm -rf /etc/NetworkManager/*
```

Then, recreate the configuration files (see [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files))

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" network-manager
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Now does not find my ethernet anymore XD