# The network shut down suddenly and doesn't restart at boot time

Tags: network-manager

I installed Ubuntu 22.03.4 LTS on a computer and everything was fine.
I use it from SSH and I installed on it NextCloud.
After some time I got some strange errors : too many requests error, then infinite redirects error.
I finally restarted the computer, and I was unable to connect to SSH anymore.

During a cold start, I see the network led blinking: cable connected and trafic incoming.
But as Ubuntu displays starting message, the interface's led suddenly turn off.
Then the start procedure remains blocked for 2 minutes on a job trying to set up the network.

When I ran the first time systemctl status NetworkManager it told me it was unable to read the /etc/network/interfaces file.
It also told me I have to adapter: lo and enp2s0

I created the file /etc/network/interfaces with this content:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

After reboot, I still have the same problem.

I can start manualy the network interface with these commands:

```
ip link set enp2s0 up
sudo dhclient -4 enp2s0
```

=> it remains up until I reboot and it actually works well

systemctl status NetworkManager still says the file /run/network/ifstate doesn't exists but I can't figure out how to create it not what to put inside.

I tried to set the ip link and dhclient commands in the /etc/rc.local file but it doesn't do anything.

I tried an update/upgrade but everything is up to date.
I tried also a --reinstall network-manager with no success.

Why has it stopped to work suddenly like this? And how to fix it?

Comment: I followed this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1225357/1751429 Now the network interface still remains up during boot time, but the boot procedure still waits for 2 minutes for a "network configuration job" and then when I login I see the adapter is up but there is no DHCP lease. I must run manualy dhclient to get one.

Comment: Hello, I finally found the origin of the problem. There was a lot of dust in the CPU and graphic card fans, making the graphic card unable to move, and the CPU's one probably totally useless. The interrior of the computer was very hot. I suspect some parts of the motherboard that were turning in security mode, with the result of the network card (PCI) to shutdown after a few minutes. I removed all the dust, and now I don't have any problem. That was not related to ubuntu itself...

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments, the problem was not software but hardware. The PCI card was shuting down due to too high temperature.
Fixed by cleaning the dust from the CPU and GPU radiators.