# How to remove configuration key in `dpkg' configuration files

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, configuration

I am seeing this when I open the terminal.

```
Unknown configuration key `foreign-architecture' found in your `dpkg'
configuration files.  This warning will become a hard error at a later
date, so please remove the offending configuration options and replace
them with `dpkg --add-architecture' invocations at the command line.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I restore configuration files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Comment: Whats the output of : `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: The output is same as what I have posted in the question.

Comment: What's the output of `grep -lFe foreign-architecture -R /etc/dpkg`? Please post the content of the matching files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue:

Step 1: Open the dpkq multiarch file

```
sudo vi /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Step 2: Remove the `foreign-architecture amd64` line and save the file