# Doveconf -n not empty after fresh install - how to update the default, if possible?

Tags: configuration, dovecot

After a fresh install of dovecot in Ubuntu 15.10, which was done after having purged the old conf, I still have a non empty doveconf -n output, but the man says that it should only output what is different from the default. So, I conclude that the default used to compute the output does not match with the actual default installation of dovecot in Ubuntu 15.10. If that is the case, is there a way to update the default used in doveconf so that it matches with the actual default configuration? Any other way to get the list of parameter definitions that are different from those of the original installation in the same format as doveconf -n, not just a mere diff, is what I am looking for.

Below is the output of `doveconf -n` after a fresh installation. Note that I have no issue with Ubuntu default.  I just want to be able to obtain in an automated manner what else is added to this Ubuntu default in the current installation in the same format as with `doveconf -n`.

```
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap pop3"
ssl = no
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible that the defaults compiled into the binaries differ from the default config files shipped by the Ubuntu packages.

Either way, you can make sure you reinstalled the original conffiles shipped by the package by using the dpkg option `--force-confmiss`, as explained at e.g. [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

BTW in case any of the configuration files aren't marked as conffiles, but they affect the program, the purge procedure is indeed necessary (and it has to be thorough, i.e. the prerm and postrm packaging scripts have to account for everything relevant).

Comment: I know how to go back to the original config files of the package. You simply have to, in one way or another,  purge them before reinstalling. The option --force-confmiss simulates that.

Comment: I will accept your answer, if you simply say that `doveconf -n`  uses the default that is hardcoded in the original package, but Ubuntu creates its own  default by modifying some parameter definitions in the configuration files, which is what `doveconf -n` outputs immediately after a fresh installation.   This is not the answer I searched. I wanted a way to compare with the default Ubuntu installation or with any other original configuration, just as in a diff,  but with the `doveconf -n` output format.    However, I don't think I will get that answer, so I would accept yours.

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually pasted this output, so that we can see the extent of changes between upstream and Ubuntu that concerns you.