# Restore php.ini to original setting in apache2 php7.0

Tags: 16.04, php7

How do I restore `php.ini` to original setting in `apache2` with `php7.0`. I have messed up the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Answer (score 2):

Just run this into your terminal

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I can confirm by looking at the package's postinst script that this is what gets done when the package is installed, and is why `dpkg -S /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you can remove php7.0 and reinstall php7.0, then file php.ini auto renew file, exist file php.ini old --> php.ini.rpmsave.
This is command help you remove and reinstall php7.0:

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.0
```

Reinstall php7.0:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```