# Distinguish true local modifications of conffiles during upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

**How can I view the differences between the current state of a conffile and the clean state when the package was installed?**

I am running Ubuntu Server upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04. The installer claims that several configuration files were changed locally:

```
Configuration file `/etc/bash.bashrc'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** bash.bashrc (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

(Source of the example: https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/)

When I choose <kbd>D</kbd> to check differences, my current conffile is compared to the clean state in the *new* package version.

Sometimes there are lots of lines that were changed between the package versions and are not local modifications for sure. I would like to filter such changes and display the true local modifications. Otherwise an important single-line local modification can be easily overlooked.

For example `php.ini` has 447 changed lines according to:

```
diff /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep -E '^[<>]' -c
```

Comment: Install etckeeper and keep your config files in version control.

Comment: @muru Thank you, [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) could help during future upgrades. However, I am primarily asking about the current one while etckeeper has not been previously installed.

Comment: Without version control, you'd probably have to obtain the original files from packages of the corresponding versions, since all dpkg does is keep track of the md5sums of conffiles.

Comment: @muru Yes, that’s exactly what I was thinking about. Is there any way to extract them without actually reinstalling the package?

Comment: Depending on what you consider reinstalling, one of my related posts could help: http://askubuntu.com/a/627018/158442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to enter shell.
2. Get the name of the package which provided the file. During a system upgrade, `apt` and `dpkg` commands point to the new version already, so you need another source to check your previous version: Open http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and enter the file name in **Search the contents of packages**. Select the system version (“distribution”) you are upgrading from.

   If you found nothing, return to the conflict resolution interface (`exit`) and press <kbd>D</kbd> to display differences. Check the diff header, it shows the desired file name:

   ```
   --- /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini 2014-01-08 00:58:08.000000000 +0100
   +++ /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production 2016-10-03 15:14:37.000000000 +0200
   ```

   In this case, it is `/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production`. Search the webpage for this file.
3. Choose the correct package name, your system’s architecture and get the URL of the package (the link below *You can download the requested file from…*).
4. Download the package.

   ```
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25_amd64.deb
   ```
5. Extract the file you want to compare.

   ```
   dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile php5-common_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25_amd64.deb | tar -x ./usr/share/php5/php.ini-production
   ```
6. Check the difference.

   ```
   diff -u /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini ./usr/share/php5/php.ini-production | less
   ```

The instructions are based on https://askubuntu.com/a/627018/250300.

Answer (score 0):

Archive(backup) your config files before modifying them.

A possible system would result in...

```
/etc
/etc/.archives
/etc/.archives/bash.bashrc.00
/etc/.archives/bash.bashrc.01
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

/etc/.archives/bash.bashrc.00 would be the original distributed version. You could use dates instead of numbers if you don't mind long names...

```
/etc/.archives/bash.bashrc.20161206.003200
```

You could write a script to make this easier too.

Comment: This is what version control is for - you should use git, mercurial, etc instead of rolling your own.