# How to restore accidentally deleted /etc/bash.bashrc, without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

In a brand new system, I mistakenly deleted `/etc/bash.bashrc`, by creating and redirecting to it, instead just appending.

How could I restore it without reinstalling the system?

As the experts here know, this is an important file in the system and I need it for proper working of the system as well as aliases.

I tried rebooting assuming it will be recreated but it isn't. In a quick Google search I found nothing (I found many results regarding restoring `~/.bashrc` but of course it's different).

How could I restore it fast without copying from another PC?

A same-PC minimal, fast, solution.

Comment: BTW, in case you didn't know, you can `set -o noclobber` to prevent mistakes like these

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Either restore that single file from bash's deb package:**

```
$ apt-get download bash
$ dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile bash_*.deb > /tmp/bash_pkg.tar
$ tar -Oxf /tmp/bash_pkg.tar ./etc/bash.bashrc | sudo tee /etc/bash.bashrc
```

**Or restore all missing files of bash:**

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall bash
```

<sub>[Read more](https://askubuntu.com/a/943680/264781)</sub>

---

There is also a file which might be helpful to you:

```
/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/bash.bashrc
```

however I believe that this file is belong to `adduser` package.

Comment: A suggestion that would make this answer more useful: first do `dpkg -S /etc/bash.bashrc` to show *which package* provides that file, in case it's unknown (in this case it's probably obvious to most people, but for a different file it might not be).