# How to re-create the repositories in /etc/apt folder in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-sources

I accidentally deleted all the files in the folder `/etc/apt` which contains `sources.list`.

Now I am not able to install any software via terminal; I get this error every time:

```
Package has no installation candidate
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: This is the seed of an answer that, if I am on the right track, I hope someone will test and expand in the answer section: see [How can I restore configuration files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files). Since you can't use APT, you'll have to download the packages listed by `dpkg -S /etc/apt` and install them using `dpkg -i`. You may need some help from [How can I restore the default repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) and I'm not sure this will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `sources.list` in `/etc/apt` directory.

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Open file with nano.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Copy following content in file.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Save it and You will be able to run

```
sudo apt update
```

and install any packages.

Comment: while copying the content it says "Read only" ..... it's not saving the changes.

Comment: Use sudo with command

Comment: yes sir i used. it's get copied successfully. but after running " sudo apt update" it shows this   
W: GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32. Run and try again.  It should work.

Comment: its shows :- Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.icm5OLsLPH/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 18 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: sudo mkdir /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/

Comment: the problem is that `sources.list` is not the only file in `/etc/apt/`. There are various other important files and directories there and APT probably will not work without them :(