# Failed to Start mysql community Server (5.7)

Tags: server, mysql

so recently new errors started to show after I reinstalled the directory `/etc/mysql` The directory looks correct after I reinstalled it using the process showing [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files), I used the method "Recover a removed Directory". Now I have issues started the MySQL server itself, I don't want to uninstall or reinstall the database because I am scared of losing files. I'll provide all details needed to try and solve this in a safe method.

Error Details:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-12-21 16:59:38 EST; 5ms ago
  Process: 3942 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3941 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 3933 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3941 (code=exited, status=2)

Dec 21 16:59:38 ns529730 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Dec 21 16:59:38 ns529730 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 21 16:59:38 ns529730 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

systemctl status command showing:

```
root@ns529730:~# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-12-21 17:10:40 EST; 14s ago
  Process: 6727 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 6720 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6727 (code=exited, status=2);         : 6728 (mysql-systemd-s)
   Memory: 15.0M
      CPU: 327ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─6728 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─6784 mysqladmin ping

Dec 21 17:10:40 ns529730 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Dec 21 17:10:41 ns529730 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04 
MySQL Version: 5.7

Comment: For future reference - unless the error messages are *very* large it's better to include them on this site as I've edited in now :) That way they'll be visible even if the pastebin you use disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed that by adding `innodb_force_recovery = 1` under [mysqld] in my `mysqld.cnf` File. You can try numbers from 1 to 10 because it may not work first time. Also for people with old mysql versions you should do that on your main config file because old versions have config files in `etc/mysql/my.cnf` but 5.7 mysql version have them in `etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
Answer taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008298/cant-start-mysql-server-database-corruption). After you do your edits try and start the mysql server using `sudo systemctl start mysql`