# Default sshd_config file for Ubunu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I've accidentally changed something in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and now `sshd` does not start.

I know I should have had a backup before editing it but it is too late now.

Can someone please show me the default content of the `sshd_config` file?

Or is there anywhere I can get it?

Comment: You can download the package from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openssh-server).  Once you have the `deb` file, you can create a temporary directory and type `dpkg-deb --extract <deb file>` to extract it.

Comment: @Ray Why not answer but comment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There should be a copy of the default config file at

```
/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config
```

(in fact, that's where the original `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file gets copied from, by the `openssh-server` package's postinstall script). You can copy that, or use `diff` to review what you changed:

```
$ diff /usr/share/openssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
122a123,125
>
> #Match Address *,!192.168.1.0/24
> #     ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Answer (score 5):

You can re-download the package from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openssh-server) for Ubuntu 20.04.

Once you have the `deb` file, you can create a temporary directory and type `dpkg-deb --extract <deb file>` to extract it.  And then look inside for the configuration file.