# How can I recreate default /etc/cron.d files?

Tags: 20.04

I deleted `/etc/cron.d/` folder by accident.

How can I recreate it to a default state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reinstall the packages with files in `/etc/cron.d` by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" \
$(dpkg -S /etc/cron.d | sed 's/,//g' | awk -F: '{print $1}')
```

Comment: Running it in bash script gives `E: Unable to locate package anacron cron e2fsprogs sysstat php-common popularity-contest`