# How can I replace the old configuration file to the new one after the release upgrade process

Tags: upgrade, configuration

During the release upgrade I accidentally chose the "keep old configuration file" option. I would rather replace it to the new one. How could I do this? The package was systemd. I tried to reinstall it manually but the question was not displayed again.

Comment: How did you try the reinstall?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)