# Why does `apt --reinstall` not bring a missing file back?

Tags: apt

Thinking that the `/etc/skel/.profile` was modified, I tried to find which package provides this file:

```
$ dpkg -S  /etc/skel/.profile 
bash: /etc/skel/.profile
$ apt-file list bash | head
bash: /bin/bash
bash: /bin/rbash
bash: /etc/bash.bashrc
bash: /etc/skel/.bash_logout
bash: /etc/skel/.bashrc
bash: /etc/skel/.profile
bash: /usr/bin/bashbug
bash: /usr/bin/clear_console
bash: /usr/share/debianutils/shells.d/bash
bash: /usr/share/doc/bash/COMPAT.gz
```

So, I moved that file and tried:

```
$ sudo apt --reinstall install bash
```

However, the file `/etc/skel/.profile` was not recreated.

1. Why is this so? I was thinking that if some files (of a package) are deleted or corrupted, I can easily restore them by using the `--reinstall` option.
2. How can I bring back a missing file from a package that it provides?

Obviously, `$ sudo apt purge bash ; sudo apt install bash` is not an option in this very specific case!

Comment: See [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Answer (score 2):

1. From your comment, to force the reinstall:

   sudo apt install --reinstall -o dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" bash
2. You could get the source package, and grab the skel.profile from it.

   sudo apt-get source bash

The package is put into your current dir as a xz compressed tar file, extract the debian/skel.profile and rename to .profile in /etc/skel

Comment: OK, for the second question. But, what about the first question? I was thinking that if some files (of a package) are deleted or corrupted, I can easily restore them by using the `--reinstall` option.

Comment: @FedKad Take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/66533/590937).

Comment: Thanks @mook765 for the pointer. So, in my case it is `sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" bash` (and it worked!). I guess @ubfan1 can update the answer too. And, you can close my question as duplicate.