# When I try to login to my user I get redirected to the login screen

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I was on the process of installing oracle on my machine I create a group and new user under the name oracle, I also remember I made some changes to a file in the `/etc` dir, but I don't recall what was the file, I search to find the tutorial I followed but I couldn't find it, after I successfully installed oracle I restart my system, and that's when it's happened

Comment: `cd /etc; ls -l --sort=time`?

Comment: @DanielT it was pam.d & ssh files

Comment: There are many reasons for a GUI login loop, for example if insufficient free space exists in $HOME (*your user directory*) a login will fail & thus a *login loop* occurs.. You'll still be able to login via text terminal (eg. Ctrl+Alt+F4 for example) in almost all of these (*exceptions exists; such as an invalid config that runs on login that causes logout - but the person who did that should be aware they did it & thus details of what was done are key*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

Comment: Also refer [Ubuntu stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)