# How to reset .bashrc to default?

Tags: bashrc

I was editing my `.bashrc` file for the /root user and I think I deleted important lines or smth.
It became `root@pop-os:~#` with a grey color like the regular font in the terminal. How to reset the `.bashrc` file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore .bashrc file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198730/how-to-restore-bashrc-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sudo cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /root/.bashrc
```

Please backup your current .bashrc in case this does not work :)

Comment: You should keep a copy of the "corrupted" one, so you can try to find your mistake: `cp /root/.bashrc{,.corrupted}`