# When coming to Ubuntu terminal always appear some kind of large list

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm a newbie to use ubuntu. Recently I installed the firefox developer edition. After that when I open my terminal always showing me the below list. How can I fix this? What is this list?

[image]

Comment: Could be code that has been inserted in your `~/.bashrc`file: that file, a bash script, is executed each time you open a terminal

Comment: @vanadium How can I solve it. Because each time I should clear my terminal.

Comment: @vanadium During that firefox installation, I typed `nano ~/.bashrc . ` I think this is the problem now I'm facing.

Comment: Remove the code that causes the display of these lines.

Comment: @vanadium seems to be now it's okay. I reset my `bashrc` to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, this is caused by extra code that was placed in your `.bashrc` configuration file. That file, a bash script, is executed each time you open a terminal. Open, inspect and correct it with a text editor, or [replace it with a default `.bashrc` file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198730/how-to-restore-bashrc-file).