# My laptop prints weird key combination while in the terminal or while startup in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, gnome-terminal

My laptop has freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS along side with Windows 10. This problem started happening when I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 (I guess). But, then I formatted my ubuntu partition back to 18.04.

But, when I open terminal, I see the following key combination being typed automatically for infinite times:

```
^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~^[[24~
```

I have tested with external keyboard too, so i feel keyboard is not an issue. Also, this happens only in terminal, not in text editor or anywhere else.

[image]

I have no clue what it is. Please help

**THIS ALSO HAPPENS WHILE BOOTING**

Comment: Check your .bashrc file. You may have included something there that causes these characters.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry for the confusion, I updated the title. It's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: If the problem persists, check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198730/how-to-restore-bashrc-file) to restore your `~/.bashrc` file to default - that might help.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I have freshly formatted my system. So, I believe `bashrc` won't be corrupt