# Terminal has extra spaces between characters on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I use ubuntu 21.04 and my terminal has extra spaces between characters.
Here is a screenshot of my terminal

[image]

I checked preferences and settings but couldn't find any option to fix it.
It also opens in a wide window.
I don't remember when it became like this, I think that it was like this since installing OS.

Comment: Is this an upgrade of an older version or a fresh installation? Fonts *can* be changed in Preferences.

Comment: It seems that you are using a custom bash theme, which is most likely responsible for the issue. Backup your current .bashrc, and check if restoring to the default .bashrc fixes the issue. If that is the issue, contact the theme maintainer to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore .bashrc file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198730/how-to-restore-bashrc-file)

Comment: Thanks @ArchismanPanigrahi, I restored .bashrc file. and start again terminal but the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, I have recently installed fresh ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why the Terminal has extra spaces between characters.

**The reason:** The font that I was using caused this issue,
when I changed the terminal font it was fixed.