# Error dpkg python

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, uninstall, python3

Without thinking much about what I was doing, I deleted the bin / python3 folder.

Now I have problems with all.

I cannot install anything. I tried too many different thing from here trying too find a solution, but nothing.

For example when I try to do sudo apt install software-properties-common, I get:

```
....
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--configure):
 installed python3-dbus package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit sta
tus 3
Setting up python3-apt (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6) ...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed

....
dpkg: error processing package python3-distro-info (--configure):
 installed python3-distro-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error e
xit status 3
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-requests-unixsocket:
 python3-requests-unixsocket depends on python3-requests; however:
  Package python3-requests is not configured yet.
 python3-requests-unixsocket depends on python3-urllib3; however:
  Package python3-urllib3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-requests-unixsocket (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-dbus
 python3-apt
 software-properties-common
 python3-six
unattended-upgrades
 python3-chardet
 python3-software-properties
 python3-certifi
 python3-gi
 python3-requests
 python3-idna
 python-setuptools
 python3-pip
 python3-urllib3
 python3-minimal
 python-dnspython
 python3-distro-info
 python3-requests-unixsocket
```

When I try to do

**`sudo apt download python3* unattended-upgrades  && sudo dpkg -i --force-all ./*.deb`**

I get the only output:

`E: Unable to locate package python3-minimal_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

I have Ubuntu 20.04

Apart from removing the python from bin I also touched the .bashrc fil.

My terminal and desktop works

**sudo apt -f install**

```
...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--configure):
 installed python3-dbus package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 3
Setting up python3-apt (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.6) ...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 installed python3-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 3
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python3-six (1.14.0-2) ...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-six (--configure):
 installed python3-six package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 3
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unattended-upgrades:
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3-apt (>= 1.9.6~); however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.
...
dpkg: error processing package python3-requests-unixsocket (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-dbus
 python3-apt
 software-properties-common
 python3-six
 unattended-upgrades
 python3-chardet
 python3-software-properties
 python3-certifi
 python3-gi
 python3-requests
 python3-idna
 python-setuptools
 python3-pip
 python3-urllib3
 python3-minimal
 python-dnspython
 python3-distro-info
 python3-requests-unixsocket
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to install python I get:

```
Setting up python3-minimal (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Sudo apt update**

```
Hit:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

At the start of the session I get:

```
bash: pyenv: command not found
```

Comment: Question, you are speaking about /var/backups/ ? If yes, how I can restore?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet)

Comment: @karel How is that relevant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency errors prevent all APT commands from running, "Package libappstream-glib8:amd64 is not configured yet"](https://askubuntu.com/q/855359/)

Comment: @someone  I'd like to build a canonical question by merging the three questions that I linked to into one question, but I haven't managed to do it yet.

Comment: @someone I certainly do need your help eventually, but I need about three months more to study the edge cases and the corner cases before I'll be ready to start trying to merge questions. What I particularly need help with is that in case there any empty holes in the canonical question where an answer should go, then I need someone to write and post that answer.

Comment: In my case I tried to get at least one python version in working condition, by creating a sym link such as: `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3`.  Then I reinstalled using `sudo apt install --reinstall python3 python python3-minimal --fix-broken`.  If you don't even have python, you may need to try other means, good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments and other answers,

First OP restored their `.bashrc` file by using [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/198730/1460940).

> First back up the old file:
>
> ```
> cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
> ```
>
> Copy the skeleton version of the file
>
> ```
> cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
> ```
>
> Load the new file:
>
> ```
> source ~/.bashrc
> ```

After that OP ran:

```
mkdir xyz && sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3* ~/xyz
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/unattended-upgrades* ~/xyz && sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common* ~/xyz
```

Then they ran:

```
sudo cp -r /var/lib/dpkg/status $HOME
echo > /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then at the end, they ran:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: It's fine.  I misunderstood.