# My ubuntu server broke after following a tutorial to upgrade python frm 3.6 to 3.8

Tags: apt, upgrade, python, dpkg

I followed this tutorial to upgrade python:

https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2019-12/upgrade-python38-on-ubuntu/

Then I ran

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

but the system refused with the error:

```
Setting up python3-apt (1.6.6) ...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 installed python3-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-update-manager:
 python3-update-manager depends on python3-apt (>= 0.8.5~); however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python3-minimal (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
E: py3compile:243: Requested versions are not installed
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 3
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3-update-manager (>= 1:18.04.11.9~); however:
  Package python3-update-manager is not configured yet.
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3-apt (>= 0.8.5~); however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-advantage-tools:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools depends on python3-apt; however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:18.04.45); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-apt
 python3-update-manager
 python3-minimal
 python3-distupgrade
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What's wrong"?

Comment: Did you read the "Disclaimer" in the red box on the webpage you mentioned?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support   *No supported release of Ubuntu uses python 3.6*

Comment: @guiverc yes I want to move to ubuntu 20, since many python libraries depend on it,18 is just too old by now. But I'm stuck.

Comment: You won't be able to *release-upgrade* to 20.04 until your `python3` is returned back to defaults; as many Ubuntu tools rely on python3 and won't work correctly if default python3 version is changed.

Comment: @guiverc  "python -V" gives me Python 3.8.0 which is correct. "python3" also opens shell on version 3.8.0

Comment: Your decisions to change the version of Python3 and to wait until the very last moment to release-upgrade were both unwise, and the consequence is that your system is now grievously damaged and no longer supported by us to assist in repair. Advice: Back up your data and clean-install a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Just if somebody fell in the same hell: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384559/error-dpkg-python 

this problem is identical to mine.. I will try to check the SYSLINKS as a final resort before doing the suggested solutions of @user535733