# Syntax error when I use Terminal caused by tor proxy

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bashrc, tor

I get this error when I open a terminal:

```
Bash: /home/admin/.bashrc: line 118: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This started after I manually edited the `.bashrc` file to remove the tor proxy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore .bashrc file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198730/how-to-restore-bashrc-file)

Comment: Please [edit] to include the output of `cat /home/admin/.bashrc` or `cat ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Look for an unterminated quoted string. You probably have an opening `"` with no closing `"`. We can help more if you show us the contents of your `.bashrc` file.