# declare -x lines appear in terminal after installing Firefox developer edition

Tags: firefox, gnome-terminal

[After I installed Firefox developer edition, this showed up in the terminal how do i remove them?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5TjU.png)

Comment: You likely have a misplaced or malformed `export` command in one of your shell's initialization files (`~/.bashrc` for example)

Comment: Check if this helps https://askubuntu.com/a/198740/124466

Comment: Also, how did you install Firefox developer edition?