# How to fix the terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, mint

the problem is that commands in the terminal are not executed, at first thought that the problem in the terminal (Gnome), reinstalled, but the problem remains.Interestingly, yesterday everything worked fine

Comment: What happened between yesterday (when it worked) and today (it doesn't work)? Problems rarely appear out of thin air. If you ran any commands whatsoever between then and now, please include those (and the iroutput) in your question. Thanks.

Comment: I made some changes to the terminal yesterday, improved its appearance according to a youtube video, but I don't think it's the problem since I uninstalled and reinstalled it today. Also yesterday I tried to run a .vbs file using wine

Comment: Yes I also think your `~/.bashrc` is messed up - you should restore it to default.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/198730/how-to-restore-bashrc-file

Comment: Restored it, but it didn't help(

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   Why your tags?  Have you made changes to your system (esp. system tools such as python3?)

Comment: Reset your terminal's settings to the defaults by running `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/` and then reopen the terminal to see if that helped and also pleas describe more how "commands are not executed" i.e. give examples of what you type and what you get in return.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem

Comment: try ``reset'' command

Comment: @steeldriver Done that ... thanks

Comment: @Desalutar Please accept Raffa's answer using the "accept answer" button. This is the usual way to say "thank you" on AskUbuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you know you altered some preferences in the Gnome terminal itself before this happened, then that might be the reason and it would be a good idea to reset all terminal preferences to their default values with:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/
```

... and of course close and reopen the terminal.