# Customized prompt does not hold when a child bash is ran

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

I have been learning bash, and while doing so I played around with the `.bash_profile` file to be able to put greeting messages etc. Later I just removed these changes. But after doing that my default configuration of prompt got lost: originally, the prompt was all in bold, and `\w` part was blue so that when I was in a deeply nested directory the prompt would not seem so entangled. I think that was the default for Ubuntu (correct me if i'm wrong), however like  I said it got lost and my prompt was non-bold and monochromatic resulting in a mess when I'm in long named directories.

So, last night I tried customizing my prompt in the fashion I mentioned above. It worked well after I added the code to `.bash_profile`

Code was like this:

```
export PS1="\[$(tput bold)\]\u@\h:\[$(tput sgr 0)\]\e[1;34m\w$ \e[m"
```

However if I try to run another bash shell in the current one, the prompt becomes unformatted:

[image]

Is that normal? Isn't the whole point of exporting a variable to make it accessible from all the child processes forked from that shell? Why it doesn't that apply to this situation?

Comment: May I ask , where did you place the `export` call ? At the end of the `~/.profile` ?

Comment: @Serg  it was in `~/.bash_profile` ,  i moved that to `~/.bashrc` and deleted the previous file since there were only the prompt customization and `ls` `grep` `dir` aliases for colored output in the file. Based on your answer i got that if there is not `~/.bash_profile` file at all, the code in the `~/.bashrc` should be sourced, for both login and non-login shells; therefore i did as you suggested and voila! thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: just put the call to `PS1` into `~/.bashrc` or call subshells with `-l` flag

Zanna's answer appropriately suggests to set `PS1` in `~/.bashrc` to be sourced by interactive shells.

You can, however , use `-l` flag to treat subshell as login shell:

```
DIR:/xieerqi|04:25|skolodya@ubuntu:
$ echo "PS1='TEST$ '" > ~/.profile

DIR:/xieerqi|04:25|skolodya@ubuntu:
$ bash
xieerqi@eagle:~$ exit

DIR:/xieerqi|04:25|skolodya@ubuntu:
$ bash -l
TEST$
```

#### The "Why"

> Is that normal? Isn't the whole point of exporting a variable to make it accessible from all the child processes forked from that shell? Why it doesn't apply to this stiuation?

Yes, that's the expected behavior. When you export something, variables should propagate downwards to subshells.

```
xieerqi@eagle:~$ export VAR=303
xieerqi@eagle:~$ bash
xieerqi@eagle:~$ echo $VAR
303
xieerqi@eagle:~$ ksh
$ echo $VAR
303
```

The issue again is `~/.bashrc` .  [The default](https://askubuntu.com/q/55552/295286) `~/.bashrc` file  has lines which override `PS1`. So, your variable *was* exported , but then uset once interactive shell sourced `~/.bashrc` . The example of this situation has been observed by [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8364/85039) on one of the questions at  [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

As  for `~/.profile` it is actually encouraged to set and export environment variables from there and is a frequent practice.

To address Zanna's comment as to why the very first shell did get colorized, I believe this is the cause:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell . . . it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, **in that order**, and reads and executes commands **from the first one**  that exists  and  is  readable. (from bash man page, emphasis added)

What happened is that once you login, `bash` finds `~/.bash_profile` and sources it as the first file found. The other shells are interactive non-login shells, so only  `~/.bashrc` is sourced after that.

Comment: @Zanna hold your horses there. Your answer is proper - people set custom prompt in `~/.bashrc` all the time. This is proper way to do it.  There is more to it however. I will update my answer at some point. As for keeping or deleting, it's of course is up to you, but i wouldn't encourage you to do that

Comment: Sure, that's how I set mine... I read your explanation, and that's exactly what I understood too, but I still don't get why `.bashrc` doesn't override the env in the first shell (it did when I tested it)

Comment: @Zanna hmm , good point.  There probably is something more to it then

Answer (score 6):

`.bash_profile` is sourced by login shells only. It has been sourced when you logged into the X-session, and the environment inherited as @Serg explains in detail. Somehow you have managed a configuration in which this environment is not overridden by `.bashrc`, perhaps setting your terminal to open a login shell by default. I can reproduce the behaviour you experienced by configuring my terminal like this:

[image]

this causes the shell to open as a login shell, but any child called will be a non-login shell, and source `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile` unless, as @Serg suggests, the `-l` flag is used.

**TL;DR**
If you want the custom prompt to be sourced by interactive shells, put the code in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Ah, yes, good catch !  The emulator plays role too