# Restore /etc/skel files

Tags: bashrc, restore, etc, skel

I have messed with `/etc/skel` files and stupidly didn't back it up! I need to restore the original files in this directory! How can I find the original files over the internet?

> **Note:** for security reasons only provide Linux official link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Others can say for sure but I wonder if you can't boot with your original Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and copy the files from there?

Comment: If you trust me, I have the `.bashrc` and `.profile` from `/etc/skel` at https://gist.github.com/edwinksl/bcebc18b73cc4480d42055f498caeb17 and https://gist.github.com/edwinksl/dafc0594176df6058bb395e985833189.

Comment: Similar: [Where I can find the contents of the default /etc/bash.bashrc file?](http://askubuntu.com/q/55552)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, `/etc/skel/.bash_logout` and `/etc/skel/.profile` are provided by package `bash`.

You need to get the bash package and extract the files from it and copy them back in `/etc/skel`.

1. Get the bash package's deb file.

   ```
   apt-get download bash
   ```
2. Then extract the package to `/`

   ```
   sudo dpkg-deb -x bash_4.3-14ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb /
   ```

   Replace the actual package file name in the above command, if your deb file name isn't exactly same.

Comment: Why wouldn't something like `sudo aptitude reinstall bash` not work?

Comment: @phihag because reinstall won't get them. they are config file

Comment: Thanks for the straight forward and simple answer, need to mention `apt download bash` is wrong, I've tried to edit it to `apt-get download bash` but it says you need to edit at least 6 chars(which the answer don't need it!). I am going to accept your answers but please fix it to the future wonders.

Comment: @Dariush aha! `apt` works in 16.04. I think you're in older version. anyway fixing this

Comment: Thanks, I've installed 16.04.1 and found it sucks(so unstable!) :D re-installed the 14.04 again, love it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the skel files from your home user dir because , at the time of user creation all skel files will be copied to the new users home directory. So as of now you can find files/ folders in your early created user home directory. Probable folders/files in /etc/skel/ are as follows:

```
.bash_logout  
.bashrc  
.config  (directory)
.profile
```

These files and folder will be there in /home/username/ where the dot(**.**) infront of it indicates they are hidden. Just take a look and copy back to /etc/skel/ . Thats it.

Comment: Home directories skel files don't remain in pristine state for long