# Why are /root/.bashrc and /etc/skel/.bashrc different on a vanilla install?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I noticed on a new Ubuntu 16.04 install that my root user's .bashrc differed slightly in behavior from a new user I had just created on the same box.

From what I can find, the root user's `.bashrc` file comes from the `base-files` package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/base-files

The /etc/skel files are provided by `bash` according to [Restore /etc/skel files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821070/restore-etc-skel-files)

Are there reasons for the difference?

Comment: Why not? At some time, somebody thought that `root` needed slightly different defaults that ordinary users. This does not mean that you cannot or should not modify the default `~root/.bashrc` or `~root/.profile`.

Comment: @AlexP I'm looking for some historical context I guess? Looking at a diff between the two, it seems like they don't have any major functional differences, except the `/etc/skel` version supports bash completion and doesn't exit immediately in non-interactive shells.

Edit: Looks like they both also exit on non-interactive shells, they just do the detection slightly differently.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it is very usual for the user to modify those files. They are not intended to be used as such. And on Ubuntu one should rarely if ever run an interactive shell as root anyway.

Comment: I'd like to point out that while the root files are bogus, nobody dares to fix them in fear of being bashed by rude people enact rules like "the focus in a terminal window should be on the output of commands" without really thinking of the best way to make this happen.